# Python BlackJack game -

Tags: python, blackjack

i want to print all cards in the deck (randomly). The program runs and prints up to 48 cards (prints different amount every time program is executed). i suspect my problem lies within the get_card() function. this is my first program so please be nice (=

```
import random

class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self,deck={},suit=[],suitDict={},cardValue=0,cardKey={}):
        self.deck=deck
        self.suit=suit
        self.suitDict=suitDict
        self.cardValue=cardValue
        self.cardKey=cardKey

    def create_deck(self):

        spades={'Ace':[1,10,11],2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:10,'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
        hearts={'Ace':[1,10,11],2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:10,'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
        diamonds={'Ace':[1,10,11],2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:10,'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
        clubs={'Ace':[1,10,11],2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:10,'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
        self.deck={'Spades':spades,'Clubs':clubs,'Hearts':hearts,'Diamonds':diamonds}
        print 'Deck Created'

    def get_card(self):
        while 1:
            #gets random suit
            self.suit=random.sample(self.deck,1)
            self.suitDict=self.deck[self.suit[0]]
            if self.suit[0] in self.deck:
                #get random key[CARD]
                self.cardKey=random.sample(self.suitDict,1)
                if self.cardKey[0] in self.suitDict:
                    #get card value
                    self.cardValue=self.deck[self.suit[0]].pop(self.cardKey[0])
                    break
                else:
                    self.get_card()
            else:
                self.get_card()
    def return_hand(self):
        self.get_card()
        return [self.suit,self.cardKey,self.cardValue]




d=Deck()
d.create_deck()
x = 52

while x!=0:
    print d.return_hand()
    x-=1
```

Comment: A function is usually a piece of code that is supposed to do a specific thing. What does `get_card` do (in your own words)? did you note that it is recursive?

Comment: explain more about what you are trying to achieve and what exactly is the problem (expected behaviour vs observed)

Comment: It simulates taking a random card from the deck. I did have that function broken into 3 functions but i figured it would be better to combine them into one function.

Comment: i'm attempting to print all 52 cards.

Comment: well, when I run it, it fails on this line `self.cardKey=random.sample(self.suitDict,1)`. because self.suitDict is already empty.

Comment: that's what i thought, i need to figure out how to remove the dictionary once it becomes empty. Is there a method to get the number of keys or values stored in a dictionary?
*found it, the len() function should do (=

Answer (score 0):

Well this answer just fixes the specific problem you're facing which is not getting all the cards from your deck. I made the minimum required changes to just make your program work. You should how ever try to make the design and code cleaner.

This is the code:

```
import random

class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self,deck={},suit=[],suitDict={},cardValue=0,cardKey={}):
        self.deck=deck
        self.suit=suit
        self.suitDict=suitDict
        self.cardValue=cardValue
        self.cardKey=cardKey

    def create_deck(self):

        spades={'Ace':[1,10,11],2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:10,'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
        hearts={'Ace':[1,10,11],2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:10,'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
        diamonds={'Ace':[1,10,11],2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:10,'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
        clubs={'Ace':[1,10,11],2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:10,'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
        self.deck={'Spades':spades,'Clubs':clubs,'Hearts':hearts,'Diamonds':diamonds}
        print 'Deck Created'

    def empty(self):
        return all(len(suit) == 0 for suit in self.deck.values())

    def get_card(self):
        while 1:
            if self.empty():
                break
            #gets random suit
            self.suit=random.sample(self.deck,1)
            self.suitDict=self.deck[self.suit[0]]
            if self.suitDict and self.suit[0] in self.deck:
                #get random key[CARD]
                self.cardKey=random.sample(self.suitDict,1)
                if self.cardKey[0] in self.suitDict:
                    #get card value
                    self.cardValue=self.deck[self.suit[0]].pop(self.cardKey[0])
                    break
                else:
                    self.get_card()
            else:
                self.get_card()

    def return_hand(self):
        self.get_card()
        return [self.suit,self.cardKey,self.cardValue]

d=Deck()
d.create_deck()
x = 52

while x!=0:
    print d.return_hand()
    x-=1
```

I suggest you run a diff between this and your code to see exactly what has changed.

Basically:

- I added an "empty()" boolean function that checks if there aren't any cards left in the deck
- I checked each time you choose a new card that the chosen `self.suitDict` is not empty before trying to randomly choose a chard from it.

Comment: This prints each card but the last ones are duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out [=

```
import random

class Deck(object):

def __init__(self,deck={}):
    self.deck=deck

def create_deck(self):

    spades={'Ace':[1,10,11],2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:10,'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
    hearts={'Ace':[1,10,11],2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:10,'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
    diamonds={'Ace':[1,10,11],2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:10,'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
    clubs={'Ace':[1,10,11],2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5,6:6,7:7,8:8,9:9,10:10,'Jack':10,'Queen':10,'King':10}
    self.deck{'Spades':spades,'Clubs':clubs,'Hearts':hearts,'Diamonds':diamonds}

def get_card(self):

    while True:
        #picks random suit from deck // picks random key from deck dict.
        #returns card attr. in a tuple
        suit=random.choice(self.deck.keys())
        if len(self.deck[suit]) > 0:
            #picks random card from suit 
            card=random.sample(self.deck[suit],1)
            cardValue=self.deck[suit].pop(card[0])
            return (suit,card,cardValue)
        else:
            #deletes empty suit from deck.      
            del self.deck[suit]
```

and then this will print out all cards randomly:

```
deck=Deck()
deck.create_deck()
for i in range(52):
    print i,deck.get_card()
```